# Access voice mail on droid device

Tags: android, xamarin.android, telephonymanager, voicemail

I am fairly new to Android development. I am using Mono for Android for development. I was just going thru the documentation on Xamarian website but i did not find any reference for accessing Voice Mail folder on the device. So i did some more search found an article on Android Developer website for `android:telephony` API. Link to that article is: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/package-summary.html.

What i am wondering is if there is a way to access user's voice mail and retrieve all the voice mails. If someone has worked on similar thing or know a resource or two, please share.

Highly appreciate your help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure this is possible if the user is utilizing their carriers default voicemail service, since you would have to connect to their service and download information on each of the messages. There may be an api for Google Voice, which would enable you to do this for any users that own and use that service for voicemail.

EDIT: to answer your question more accurately, Voicemail isn't stored on the local device in most instances. Therefore you need to access the users voicemail service in order to gain information on their messages.

Comment: if i am correct, voicemails do get downloaded on the device. If not, how are you able to listen to your voicemails even if there is no network reception.

Comment: As I mentioned it all depends on the service you use. I know accessing my Verizon voicemail requires me to make a phone call to their voicemail service.

But I primarily use google Voice. As I mentioned, that behaves differently. I know it downloads information about the voicemail, but I don't know how much, or if you're allowed to access this information. 

Though this api may help you in your endeavor. But once again it only works for Google Voice.
http://code.google.com/p/google-voice-java/

Comment: Thank you. I will check it. Or may be i may end up writing my app restricted to the carrier.

Comment: Be careful with that, the carrier may provide their own service and might not want competition. Which means you may have to jump through hoops just to be able to access their system, only to wind up with a cease and desist order.